# Better way to solve: B[8] = (i - j) + A[20]?

Tags: mips

For background,

A[20] = s0 , B[8] = s1, i = s4 and j = s5

So a classmate helped me with this and got:

```
lw t0,80(s0)
add t0, t0,s4
Sub t0,t0,s5
sw to,32(s1)
```

Wouldnt it be better/possible to have a:

```
lw t0,80(s0)
sub t1,s4,s5  for i - j
add t2, t0,t1  for A[20] + (i-j)
sw t2, 32(s1)
```

Now I don't know if what I thought could be the answer is correct, but hopefully I am on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are basically like:

```
val = a[20]
val = val + i 
val = val - j 
b[8] = val
```

vs.

```
val = a[20]
diff = i - j
result = val + diff
b[8] = result
```

Both of these should accomplish the same thing, and do so in the same number of instructions.

Your version subtracts `i-j`, then adds the difference to `a[20]`, then stores it in `b[8]`. Your classmate's version adds `a[20]` and `i`, then subtracts `j` from that sum, then stores the result in `b[8]`. It's basically just a different order of doing the same things.

Your classmate's version does use fewer registers though. This doesn't make it better per se, but idk someone might consider it preferable for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is better for the following reasons:

1. It is true to the original expression
2. It may reduce chances for overflow: (A + i) - j could overflow when A + ( i - j ) wouldn't necessarily (and see 1, being true to the original expression here means it will behave the same)
3. The load of `t0` is not used in the next cycle so the load-use delay is covered — it will actually run 1 cycle faster than the alternative

Let's note that `sub` and `add` instructions will trap on overflow.  It is not stated in the question whether overflow is of interest or important.  To ignore overflow entirely, use `subu` and `addu` instead.